# printing richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#

I have richtextbox and preview dialog.
when I want to make a preview I want to see all the pages of the richtextbox but now I can see only the fist page many times.

please help me

```
char[] param = { '\n' };
string [] lines = {};

if (pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == PrintRange.Selection)
{
   lines = rtb.SelectedText.Split(param);
}
else
{
   lines = rtb.Text.Split(param);
}

int i = 0;
char[] trimParam = { '\r' };
foreach (string s in lines)
{
   lines[i++] = s.TrimEnd(trimParam);
}
int linesPrinted = 0;
int x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
int y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(rtb.ForeColor);

while (linesPrinted < lines.Length)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[linesPrinted++],
        rtb.Font, brush, x, y);
   y += 15;
   if (y >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
   {
       e.HasMorePages = true;
       return;
   }
   else
   {

       e.HasMorePages = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you have this method in the print page even, every time that a new page is printed you read again the content of the RichTextBox :

```
lines = rtb.Text.Split(param);
```

And you start again from the beginning ...

So you have to read the RichTextBox content only in the first page ...
To resolve this problem you can for example declare a variable outside of the method :

```
private int printPage = 0 ;
```

And externalize from the method the variables :

```
string [] lines = {};
int linesPrinted = 0;
```

The new code become (I haven't tested it - is only a proof of concept) :

```
 if(printPage <= 0) {
   //First Page
   char[] param = { '\n' };
   linesPrinted = 0;
   if (pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == PrintRange.Selection)
   {
       lines = rtb.SelectedText.Split(param);
   }
   else
   {
       lines = rtb.Text.Split(param);
   }
  }
   int i = 0;
   char[] trimParam = { '\r' };
   foreach (string s in lines)
   {
       lines[i++] = s.TrimEnd(trimParam);
   }

   int x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
   int y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
   Brush brush = new SolidBrush(rtb.ForeColor);

   while (linesPrinted < lines.Length)
   {
       e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[linesPrinted++],
            rtb.Font, brush, x, y);
       y += 15;
       if (y >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
       {
           e.HasMorePages = true;
           printPage++;
           return;
       }
       else
       {
           e.HasMorePages = false;
       }
   }
```